# Bizarre permission denied problem accessing images on a web server

Tags: html, apache, file-permissions

I am unable to figure this out. I was creating a new page to display entries to a photo contest and it's not working for some reason I can't figure out. The new page is almost a clone of an existing page from an earlier photo contest that is working. After spending hours trying to figure it out, I'm stumped.

I'm running an Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at home for testing web sites. In this case the file structure is like:

```
    site/images/contestname/
```

where I have multiple contest names, each with its own directory. The directory permissions are the same in each case - the default for any directory created below "images", which is the default for any directory created in the "site".

The photos in all the directories all have the same ownership and permissions too - owner me, group www-data, with a+r (owner and group can also write).

The simplest manifestation of the problem is if I use a web browser to view the directory (http://mylocalsite/images/contestname/). This shows the list of files in the directory but when I try to view one, I get:

```
    Forbidden
    You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

It's only happening in this one directory. In all the others, I can click on a file name and see the image. I've tried recreating the directory and moving the images to the new one but that didn't change anything. It's also not browser related as it's happening with both Firefox and Chromium.

Does anyone have any idea on what the problem may be?

Comment: So, the permission of the directory is 775 (rwxrwxr-x)?  Do you have an .htaccess file that is blocking you?  Remember that won't be shown in a plain `ls`.  You need `ls -a`.

Comment: No. This is my local server. I have no access restrictions. 

However I just noticed that there is + at the end of the access permissions which read -rw-rw-r--+ while in the other directorie, the + is absent.

I had been using Dolphin to look at the file permissions and it doesn't show anything unusual. ..

Comment: Is that for the files or the directory?  A directory has to have `x` permission in order for you to use its contents.

Comment: It was on the files. I ran setfacl -nb * to remove it. Things are working now. 

I have no idea how an acl got attached to the files.

Thanks!